# Are Dafny "reals" really "real"

Tags: z3, dafny, boogie

I want to prove statements about derivatives and limits, but I failed to make progress, so I wondered whether Dafny's `real` type actually coincides with the real numbers.

Dafny's documentation states:

> Dafny supports *numeric types* of two kinds, *integer-based*, which includes the basic type `int` of all integers, and *real-based*, which includes the basic type `real` of all real numbers

So I assume that I can prove all statements about (values of type) `real` that I could prove about real numbers.

As far as I understand, Dafny itself doesn't specify the axioms of real numbers. It transpiles to boogie, which in turn relies on SMT solvers, usually z3. [z3](https://microsoft.github.io/z3guide/docs/theories/Arithmetic) points to SMT-Lib's [Reals](https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-Reals.shtml) theory, which states "real closed field" axioms, which I hope are the basis of z3 and thereby boogie and Dafny reals.

Based on these I tried

```
lemma all_positive_elements_have_a_square_root(x: real)
  requires x >= 0.0
  ensures exists root: real :: x == root * root
{}
```

But it fails to verify. I won't put in more effort, because - not knowing the axioms - I don't know how to help the verifier.

I tried to convince myself that z3 reals fare better:

```
$ cat /tmp/reals.z3 
(declare-const x Real)
(assert (= (* x x) 2.0))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
$ z3 /tmp/reals.z3 
sat
(
  (define-fun x () Real
    (root-obj (+ (^ x 2) (- 2)) 1))
)
```

[What is `root-object` in z3 with Real theory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69734745/what-is-root-object-in-z3-with-real-theory) explains the meaning of this output and it indeed shows that z3 can prove the existence of a real number with the desired property, which does not follow from ordered field axioms alone.

Dafny, again, fails to verify this:

```
lemma sqrt2_exists()
  ensures exists root: real :: 2.0 == root * root
{}
```

So is there a way to make use of the fact that Dafny `reals` or not just `rationals`, i.e. have completeness?

Update:
I'd like to clarify that even though it may pedantic, I am not looking for answers that work around the actual question. Defining functions like `sqrt` axiomatic (without body) or proving lemmas about passed in variables that, by precondition, are irrational can be useful workarounds for many use cases, but they don't answer the question whether Dafny's reals deserve their name.

Of course these answers might help others that are less pedantic :)

Furthermore, if the answer is "It is theoretically possible, but nobody has ever done it.", then I would appreciate some detail as to why it is so hard. Why is proving `1 + 1 == 2` trivial while proving `exists root: real :: 2 == root * root` is hard, even though both follow almost immediately from z3's axioms and z3 has no trouble proving them?

Answer (score 2):

You can prove the existence of square roots in Dafny using other axioms rather than just asserting their existence. Using some of the definitions in the original realAnalysis file I linked you can define them as the least upper bound of the reals squared that are less than the number.

In this case we need to call only 1 axiom, CompletenessAxiomUpper, which basically asserts that if given a bounded set of reals, which is not empty, then there exists a supremum.

The calculations get a bit gnarly in one case and require a few lemmas to verify.

```
//https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_Square_Roots_of_Positive_Real_Number
lemma sqrtExists(r: real)
    requires r > 0.0
    ensures exists y :: r == y * y
{
    if r == 1.0 {
        assert r == r*r;
    }else{
    var S := iset x | x*x < r ;
    assert upperBound(S, r+1.0);
    forall x | x in S 
        ensures x < r+1.0
    {}

    forall y | y > r+1.0
        ensures y*y !in S
    {
        var r' := r +1.0;
        assert r' > 1.0;
        assert y > 1.0;
        assert y > r';
    }
    assert 0.0 in S;
    assert forall x :: x in S ==> x < r+1.0;
    CompletenessAxiomUpper(S,r+1.0);
    var u :| sup(S, u);
    if u*u > r {
        ArchimedeanPrinciple((u*u-r)/(2.0*u));
        var n: pos :| 1.0/(n as real) < (u*u-r)/(2.0*u);
        var u' := (u-1.0/(n as real));
        assert u' == sub(u,1.0/(n as real));
        assume upperBound(S, u');
        assert false;
    }
    if u*u < r {
        assert upperBound(S, u);
        assert u in S;
        if u < 0.0 {
            assert !upperBound(S, u);
            assert false;
        }else if u > 0.0 {
            assert (r-u*u)/(4.0*u) > 0.0;
            ArchimedeanPrinciple((r-u*u)/(4.0*u));
            ArchimedeanPrinciple(2.0*u);
            var na: pos :| 1.0 / (na as real) < ((r-u*u)/(4.0*u));
            var nb: pos :| 1.0 / (nb as real) < (2.0*u);
            var n := if na > nb then na else nb;
            NaturalFraction(n, nb);
            NaturalFraction(n, na);
            var nf := 1.0 / (n as real);
            assert nf > 0.0;
            assert 1.0 / (n as real) < 2.0*u;
            assert nf < 2.0*u;
            assert 1.0 / (n as real) < ((r-u*u)/(4.0*u));
            var u' := u+1.0/(n as real);
            calc {
                u'*u';
                (u+1.0/(n as real))*(u+1.0/(n as real));
                u*u+(2.0*u/(n as real))+(1.0/((n as real )*(n as real)));
            }
            calc {
                nf * nf;
                (1.0/((n as real )*(n as real)));
            }
            calc {
                nf * 2.0*u;
                (2.0*u/(n as real));
            }
            multLte(nf,2.0*u,nf);
            assert nf * nf < nf *(2.0*u);
            assert (1.0/((n as real )*(n as real))) < (2.0*u/(n as real));
            assert u*u+(2.0*u/(n as real))+(1.0/((n as real )*(n as real))) < u*u+(2.0*u/(n as real))+(2.0*u/(n as real));
            calc {
                (2.0*u/(n as real))+(2.0*u/(n as real));
                (4.0*u/(n as real));
            }
            assert r-u*u > (4.0*u/(n as real)) by {
                assert 1.0 / (n as real) < ((r-u*u)/(4.0*u));
                assert (n as real) >= 1.0;
                calc {
                1.0 / (n as real) < ((r-u*u)/(4.0*u));
                (4.0*u)* (1.0 / (n as real)) < (4.0*u)*((r-u*u)/(4.0*u));
                (4.0*u)* (1.0 / (n as real)) < (r-u*u);
                (4.0*u / (n as real)) < (r-u*u);
                }
            }
            assert u*u+(2.0*u/(n as real))+(2.0*u/(n as real)) <= u*u + (r - u*u);
            assert u' * u' < u*u+(2.0*u/(n as real))+(2.0*u/(n as real)) <=r ;
            assert u' * u' < r ;
            assert u' in S;
            assert false;
        }else if u == 0.0 {
            assert upperBound(S, 0.0);
            if r > 1.0 {
                assert 1.0 * 1.0 < r;
                assert 1.0 in S;
                assert false;
            }else {
                assert 0.0 < r < 1.0;
                var rs := r * r;
                smallerThanR(r,rs);
                assert rs in S;
                assert false;
            }
            assert false;
        }
    }
    
    assert u*u == r;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/hath995/Dafny4.4/blob/main/realAnalysis.dfy#L189 for the full definitions.

Comment: I appreciate the effort that must have gone into this proof. Now a proof of `CompletenessAxiomUpper` (and `assume upperBound(S, u')`, but that's a smaller issue, I assume) is required to make this an answer to the question :)

Comment: Ah yeah I meant to come back to that assume. I am pretty sure I can fix that. As for proving the axiom of completeness, apparently it can be done by constructing the reals with Cauchy sequences. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_Cauchy_sequences) Given the wiki, I imagine it can be done, but it's definitely challenging. I will leave that assignment to you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain how to verify that statement. However, Dafny can reason about real numbers.

```
function div(x: real, y: real): (z: real)
    requires y != 0.0
{
    x/y
}

lemma sqrt(x: real, y: real) 
    requires x > 0.0
    requires y > 0.0 && y*y ==x
{
    assert div(x, y) == y;
    var sq :| sq != 0.0 && div(x, sq) == sq;
}
```

It seems like the standard approach is to require it's existence as an axiom and Dafny accepts it.

[One implementation](https://github.com/wilcoxjay/notes/blob/bb0a8441c25e90ef0c63ba99add993ed0a349932/SquareRoot.dfy#L4)

As for defining derivatives, that will be a good bit of work. I implemented some basic definition and examples of limits of sequences [here](https://github.com/hath995/dafny/blob/main/math/realAnalysis.dfy). If you can extend it all the way to derivatives I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: In your example, the verifier can prove the existence of a witness for `exists sq: real :: sq != 0.0 && div(x, sq) == sq` by using `y` and the precondition `y*y ==x`. My question is about proving the existence without passing the witness as an argument to the proof. Also the linked "implementation" does not have a body, so Dafny does not prove that this function can be implemented. Dafny also accepts the function (without body) when I remove the `x >= 0` precondition, which would allow me to use `var x: real := Sqrt(-1.0)`. `dafny audit` provides a warning.

Comment: I understand your question and I don't know of any method to construct an irrational real. There is another question here in SO, where one of the Dafny experts asserts that it doesn't not provide methods to create irrationals. However, the axiom approach can take you fairly far. Here is another example. As long as the logic is consistent then you can prove what you need about reals. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76768309/how-to-define-exponential-and-log-function-for-real-variables-in-dafny/76771586

Comment: And I also argue that you rarely are concerned with an actual real value but rather that the relationships of it to other values is maintained.

Comment: Dafny's `real`s are indeed real numbers. The verifier has an incomplete understanding of the reals, so it may not be able to prove everything you expect to be true. Carefully adding your own axioms (a body-less `lemma` that you can mark with `{:axiom}`) can give you a way to balance what you take responsibility for and what Dafny proves. There are no compiled operations that produce irrational reals. But you can, for example, write a method that approximates sqrt(2) to a given level of precision--the specification of this method would say that its result squared is close to 2.

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't directly answer the question, so I'll not accept it. However it helped me in understanding a critical point about Dafny's real numbers.

Why shouldn't `real` be called `rational` or some other number system whose axioms/properties we can prove `real` to satisfy? Wouldn't that be more natural than to state that Dafny's reals are indeed real numbers even though this fact doesn't seem to be usable?

My answer: Adding completeness axioms doesn't lead to contradictions (I hope!). If we `assume` completeness of a hypothetical `rational` type, we would be able to derive `false` by using completeness to get a "rational square root of 2" and then show that square root of 2 is not a rational number.

The other way around, we can't prove that `real` is actually the set of rational numbers, because we can't prove that irrational numbers are not in `real`. E.g. we can't prove `forall r: real :: exists p: nat, q: nat :: r == p as real / q as real`.

So even though apparently we can't prove that `real` is the set of real numbers, we can't prove that it is the set of rational numbers either. Furthermore, assuming completeness (hopefully) doesn't lead to contradictions, so there is an argument that `real` resembles the real numbers more than the rational numbers.

That being said, I cannot rule out that we could add `forall r: real :: exists p: nat, q: nat :: r == p as real / q as real` as an axiom without being able to derive contradictions either.

Comment: There was another question on stackoverflow, which I can't find now which said that the reals that are representable in Dafny were the algebraic numbers. However, here is a proof that a real is not rational in Dafny. 

https://github.com/dafny-lang/teaching-material/blob/main/Exercises/Sqrt2IrrationalFun_solution.dfy#L55

Comment: The proof relies axiomatically on the existence of the irrational number `Sqrt(2.0)`. I should put "When I say 'prove' I mean 'prove without relying on user-defined axioms'" into my signature :)

Comment: I just gave you a proof of the existence of a square root. Yes, you point out that it relies on an axiom. This axiom is taught in most undergrad analysis classes. You can make it a theorem if you try to define Cauchy sequences in Dafny. Btw, Rustan Leino is the architect of Dafny so if he says Dafny reals are Z3 reals, then that means you can push Dafny as far as Z3 + axioms allow. If Dafny could prove it without help then the lemma for their existence would immediately verify. I would say that Dafny cannot prove it without using some axiom.

Comment: Also, you can generate a boogie file (.bpl) from any given .dfy and then inspect the axioms which Dafny is aware of.